# Manipulating matrices in C through R

Tags: c, r, matrix

I want to write some matrix manipulation functions in C, and then pass them onto R, where the matrix will be provided by R, and get the results of the manipulations. I have a test function as shown below (please don't mind what it does, in my original functions, I will need to pick a random element from each row, and do some computation on them, and return an array composed of those randomly chosen elements from each row, in other words, I must have two for loops to go through all the elements of the matrix).

```
void multMat(double **A, int *r, int *c, double *s)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < *r; ++i)
    {

       for (j = 0; j < *c; ++j) 
       {
           if (j == 5)
               s[i] = A[i][j] * A[i][0];
       }
    }
}
```

I compiled this with `R CMD SHLIB multMat.c`, and it produces `multMat.so` for me. Then, on the R side, I have something like this:

```
dyn.load("multMat.so")

multMat <- function(A)
{
  .C("multMat", A=as.double(A), r=as.integer(nrow(A)), c=as.integer(ncol(A)), s=as.double(nrow(A)))
}
```

Afterwards, I created a test matrix like in R Studio and called this function:

```
A <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
multMat(A)
```

The problem is that when I run this function, R Studio crashes. I guess there is some problem with how the C function is defined. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe use Rcpp package?

Comment: @zx8754 I used that one too, was trying to use pure C solution now.

Comment: Added the tag (feel free to remove), thought rcpp was developed for exactly this reason.

Comment: Removed tag as this uses R's pure C interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Where you are wrong**

You define `A` as `double **`,

```
void multMat(double **A, int *r, int *c, double *s)
```

while passing a `double *`:

```
.C("multMat", A=as.double(A), r=as.integer(nrow(A)), c=as.integer(ncol(A)), s=as.double(nrow(A)))
```

You should rewrite you C function using 1 dimensional array. Define your function as:

```
void multMat(double *A, int *r, int *c, double *s)
```

and replace `A[i][j]` by `A[j * r + i]`. (If I did not get you wrong, `r` is the leading dimension.)

**Performance issue:**

At the moment, it is `i-j` loop with `j-loop` as the inner loop, so that you are scanning a row of the matrix in the innermost loop. This is **not cache friendly**. You should interchange loop to get `j-i` loop.

I reckon that you are in fact aware of the cache issue. In C, matrices are stored in row-major-order, so `i-j` loop is optimal; but in R, matrices are stored in column-major-order, so `j-i` loop is optimal.

Perhaps the different storage style of matrices will cause some problem of your existing code. You may think it twice here. Your original C code assumes it takes a matrix that is stored by row, while if you initialize your matrix in R and feed it to C, it is stored by column. Possibly some changes are needed. If this results in too much change of your code, you may try passing the transpose of your R matrix to C.

You should also **use more local/automatic variables in your C code, instead of using pointers**. For example, replace

```
for (i = 0; i < *r; ++i)
```

by

```
int r_local = *r;
for (i = 0; i < r_local; ++i)
```

You get performance boots by **CPU register reusing** and **instruction reduction** (no need to dereference the point every iteration).

**R supported C/FORTRAN data type**

> So, there is no way to directly pass the matrix from R, and then use the casual convention for matrix, meaning `A[i][j]` in C side?

No, there isn't. R does not support `double **`. Matrices in R are stored in column-major-format into a long vector, and belong to `double *` type.

```
R storage mode  C type        FORTRAN type
logical         int *         INTEGER
integer         int *         INTEGER
double          double *      DOUBLE PRECISION
complex         Rcomplex *    DOUBLE COMPLEX
character       char **       CHARACTER*255
raw unsigned    char *        none
```

See [section 5.2 of Writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran).