# .C() returns me an empty list

Tags: c, r, dll, fortran, load

I'm a beginner in R and I'm trying to load a `.dll` file, named `dll.dll`, that's written in C, into R. It seems to work, now I want to use the functions that are stored in the `.dll` file and I encounter problems.

I've searched for a solution or other method in manuals, here and on google. Would be very thankful if I could get a suggestion of what to use or any idea!

My code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/MyUser/R")
dyn.load("dll.dll")
is.loaded("DLL_FUNK") 
# For some reason True with capital letters, not in lower case
output <- .C("DLL_FUNK", in9 = as.integer(7))
#output # R Crashes before I can write this.
# R Crashes
# In outdata.txt: "in-value=   139375128"
```

The function should return a number, 1955. But I can't seem to get to that value. What am I doing wrong?

Update with code (Fortran runned as C), this is the code in dll.dll:

```
subroutine  dll_funk(in9) 
implicit none

!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
!***      Declarations: variables, functions
!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
integer(4) :: in9
!integer :: in9


! Definitions of variables in the external function calls
!!dec$ attributes c,alias :'dll_funk' :: dll_funk 
!dec$ attributes dllexport            :: dll_funk
!dec$ attributes value                :: in9

open(194,file='outdata.txt')
write(194,*) 'in-value=', in9
! in9 = 1955
close(194)

end subroutine
!end function
```

So now when it runs, R crashes but before it writes to my file (outdata.txt) but it't not my number, maybe some kind of address...

Another question, do you recommend me to run the code with .C and from C run the Fortran code or is it better to run it with .Fortran with only Fortran code? 
It seems like .Fortran have problem handling strings, or that's what I understood from: [Interface func .C and .Fortran](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran)

Comment: You may be missing a `"` in your call. Try `dyn.load("2dll.dll")`

Comment: Finally got it to work, by deleting all Definitions and make the code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did not you pass any arguments to your C function `dll_function`? When you use `.C()`, you have to pass function arguments as a list. `.C()` will return modified list. So, If you pass in nothing, you get nothing.

What does your C function `dll_function` looks like? Note that:

1. `dll_function` must be a `void` C function, with no return values. If this function should return something, it must return by modifying function arguments;
2. all function arguments of `dll_function` must be pointers.

---

**Follow-up**

> The dll_function is only to test if I can get access to it.

You can use `is.loaded()` after `dyn.load()` to test whether you have access to the C function:

```
dyn.load("dll.dll")
is.loaded("dll_function")  ## TRUE
```

Note that, `is.loaded` takes C function name, while `dyn.load()` takes `.dll` name. In general you can have multiple functions in a single `.dll` file. You can use `is.loaded()` to check either of them, to test whether shared library has been loaded successfully.

> So if I want it to return something, I should give it an argument (of same type?)?

Yes. The other answer here does give a toy example. You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37655028/4891738) I made half a month ago. At the bottom there is a summary of variable type.

Answer (score 0):

When using `.C`, the extra arguments passed to `.C` are copied and passed on as pointers to the called c-function. This function can then modify the data pointer to by the pointers. The return value of the function is ignored by `.C`. So, you c-function should look something like:

```
void dll_function(int* result) {
  /* Do some complicated computation that results in 1955 */
  (*result) = 1955;
}
```

And your call from R:

```
.C("dll_function", integer(1))
```

An example with input (this calculates the sum of an integer vector; this example assumes that there are no missing values in vector):

```
void dll_function2(int* result, int* vector, int* length) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < (*length); ++i, ++vector) {
    sum += (*vector)
  }
  (*result) = sum;
}
```

Called from R:

```
x <- c(1000, 900, 55)
.C("dll_function2", integer(1), as.integer(x), length(x))[[1]]
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thought about adding it as an edit to your answer, but it seemed a bit too large for an edit.